# Strange remote desktop login into another server

Tags: windows

i have been accessing our remote server which is located outside our windows domain using and ip address. When i entered the ip address this morning it brought the remote desktop window as usual but was refusing to accept my log in credentials. Then i decided entered my domain admin password just for a try, but to my surprise i was logged into another machine on the domain which is the dns server. I physically went to the site and managed to login and restarted the machine but still its giving the same problem on all the domain computers when i try to access the remote server.

Comment: Duplicate IP address?  Gremlins?  Servers installed on an ancient Indian burial ground?

Comment: Is it a public or private IP address? Sounds like the IP has been put into use inside your dns domain.

Comment: it is a public ip address which sites outside our network. I was able to login yesterday without any problems.

Comment: Sounds like someone messed with the router or the server grabbed a new IP...

Comment: i checked the IP address from the remote site and it is still the same. This is really strange.

Comment: I have discovered that it is just a general problem as all the connections to any remote machine are routing to DNS. Can anyone please help me we are using untangle as a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This to me sound like to could be a SNAT issue.  Could your firewall or untangle be directing all RDP (assuming that is what you are using) traffic to the DNS server?

Comment: Someone had changed the configurations in the firewall to redirect all remote desktop traffic to the DNS